# Order a list of items based off number of Likes

Tags: list, button

I have a list of items with each having a like button and number of likes. I need to order then based off the number of likes. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

```
<div>
  <h1>Ranking</h1>
  <!-- The list -->
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h4>Item 1</h4>
      <p>200 likes</p>
      <p><a href="">&#9829; like?</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>Item 2</h4>
      <p>100 likes</p>
      <p><a href="">&#9829; like?</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>Item 3</h4>
      <p>50 likes</p>
      <p><a href="">&#9829; like?</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>Item 4</h4>
      <p>25 likes</p>
      <p><a href="">&#9829; like?</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>Item 5</h4>
      <p>1 likes</p>
      <p><a href="">&#9829; like?</a></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
function sortAlpha(a,b){  
    // here we take the number of likes
    var aLikes = parseFloat($(a).children("p").first().html());
    var bLikes = parseFloat($(b).children("p").first().html());
    return aLikes > bLikes? 1 : -1;  
};  

$('div ul li').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('ul');
```